# sending mail working locally but not in server

Tags: php

I've already searched, and none of the questions here helped me to solve my problem.

I have to send an email on the website that I'm working on, it works locally, but when I try sending one on the server, it gives me a fatal error.

the code:

send_mail.js

```
$(function() {
   $('.enviar').click(function(){
      event.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
      url: 'modules/send_mail.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data : {
        nome : $('#nome').val(),
        mail : $('#mail').val(),
        assunto : $('#assunto').val(),
        mensagem : $('#mensagem').val()
      },
      success: function (data) {
         console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(xhr, textStatus, data) {
        console.log(xhr.statusText);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
   });
});
```

send_mail.php

```
<?
include_once ('../config.php');

$mail_to = "ricardo.ac.dc@gmail.com";
$nome = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['nome']));
$mail = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['mail']));
$assunto = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['assunto']));
$mensagem = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['mensagem']));

$texto = $nome ."(". $mail . ")\r\n";
$texto .= $mensagem;

mail ($mail_to,$assunto,$texto);    
?>
```

form.php

```
<div class="form_contactos">
   <div class="form_text">
      <input name="nome" id="nome" placeholder=" nome" type="text" class="linha_simples"/>
      <input name="mail" id="mail" placeholder=" e-mail" type="email" class="linha_simples"/>
      <input name="assunto" id="assunto" placeholder=" assunto" type="text" class="linha_simples"/>
   </div>

   <textarea name="mensagem" id="mensagem" placeholder=" mensagem"  class="caixa_texto"></textarea>
   <input type="submit" name="enviar" class="submit_button enviar" id="enviar" value="" />

</div>
```

config.php

```
<?php

$ligacao = 'local';

if ($ligacao == 'server')
{
    //Para ligar a SQL Server, utilizar PHP 5.2.6 (Wampserver 2C)
    $servidor = "localhost";
    $utilizador = "s002349_admin";
    $password = "Torre2008";
    $bd = "s002349_temp_almadados";

}
else
{

    //Para ligar a SQL Server, utilizar PHP 5.2.6 (Wampserver 2C)
    $servidor = "localhost";
    $utilizador = "root";
    $password = "root";
    $bd = "almadados";
}


//Ligação à BD
$padrao = mysql_connect($servidor, $utilizador, $password)
or die("Erro ao ligar a $servidor");

//Selecção de BD a utilizar
$seleccao = mysql_select_db($bd, $padrao)
or die("Erro ao aceder a $bd");

?>
```

The error that I receive is this one:

> **Fatal error**:  Function name must be a string in
>   **/home/s002349/public_html/almadados.net/new_site/modules/send_mail.php**
>   on line **26**
>   send_mail.js:22

Can anyone help me with this problem?

> I thought of something that could work... I'm going to have to
>   implement [phplist](http://phplist.com) on this site, so my idea was to send this mail also
>   by the phplist, could this work, and solve my problem?

*I've cleared all the blank lines on the send_mail.php and cleared all the cache on the browser, so I don't understand why it still shows that line*

Comment: Could you put a comment next to line 26?

Comment: that is one of my problems, there is no line 26...

Comment: @RicardoAlves Can you comment what line 25?

Comment: the php file only has 14 lines, so that is really weird, can it be in cache from a previous version?

Comment: There has to be more to the PHP file than what you've posted. There are nowhere near enough lines.

Comment: when you include a file, it become part of the code that includes it. paste the configurations file to the question and and paste a dump of `$mail_to,$assunto,$texto` please

Comment: How long is your Config.php because it got included befor any code so lets say your Config.php is 37 lines long the 3rd lines of send_mail.php would actually be line 40 not line 3.

Comment: It is possible that the error would be in Config.php. Could you post Config.php??

Comment: I think there is something wrong with `$padrao = mysql_connect($servidor, $utilizador, $password)
or die("Erro ao ligar a $servidor");
     
      $ErrorLog = new cLog($Log['FR'], $Log['EN'], false, false, false);
     
      return $ErrorLog;`

Comment: Try replacing `or die("Erro ao ligar a $servidor");` for `if(!$padrao){die("Erro ao ligar a ".$servidor);}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing change this `<?` to this `<?php`, some server cannot support short tags

After if npt work, try to change this:

```
mail ($mail_to,$assunto,$texto);
```

to this:

```
mail($mail_to,$assunto,$texto);
```

There is a blank space between the function name and brackets

**UPDATE**
change this:

```
$padrao = mysql_connect($servidor, $utilizador, $password)
or die("Erro ao ligar a $servidor");
```

to this:

```
$padrao = mysql_connect($servidor, $utilizador, $password)
if (!$padrao)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
```

same thing for the variable `$seleccao`

Comment: the only thing i didn't post was the php file that has the form, will it help?

Comment: post all your code, maybe there is something wrong,  please post it @RicardoAlves

Comment: you have more code into your send_mail.php please cancel all lines empty before the end of the file if there is some, because you have 26 lines not only the lines that you have posted try please @RicardoAlves

Comment: Short tags are'nt the issue here. If the server could'nt process short tags it would probably rendered it as HTML so @Ricardo would'nt have any error code exepte maybe an HTML error.

Comment: edit answer try now please changing all mysql_connect @RicardoAlves

Comment: tried it and I get the same error, sorry @AlessandroMinoccheri

Answer (score 0):

This could be because the server doesn't support short tags. I highly suggest staying away from these. Replace `<?` with `<?php`

Comment: I always use short tags on this server, I have other sites that are using shot tags, and also, on all the other pages I use the short tags, but can it make a difference?

Comment: Well if it's working for other sites on the same server, then this is probably not the issue since it's a global configuration. Check your php.ini for `short_open_tag` to see if it is configured to support it. http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
or die("Erro ao ligar a $servidor");
```

for

```
if(!$padrao){die("Erro ao ligar a ".$servidor);}
```